# Xml parsing second label

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am parsing a XML with php *`simplexml_load_file`* function. XML is;

```
<item>
 <Title>TEST</Title>
 <Image primary="true"/>
 <Image>
  http://www.domain.com/image.jpg
 </Image>
</item>
```

I am parsing title label truely with;

```
$var->item->Title
```

But parsing image label is giving false result with;

```
$var->item->Image
```

How can I fetch; `http://www.domain.com/image.jpg` result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is formatted improperly-- if you have multiple images and you want to set one as primary, you'd use

```
<item>
<Title>TEST</Title>
<Images>
    <Image primary="true">http://www.domain.com/image1.jpg</Image>
    <Image>http://www.domain.com/image2.jpg</Image>
</Images>
</item>
```

Then loop through the `Images` array in PHP to access the path to the image.

Alternately if you know you're only using a single image, set the `Primary` attribute on the same image node:

```
<item>
<Title>TEST</Title>
<Image primary="true">http://www.domain.com/image1.jpg</Image>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This xml is external file. And so i can't modify this.

Comment: Then you'd have to access the `Image` as an array and choose the second one: `$var->item->Image[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can get attribute of "Image" node like this

```
var_dump($var->Title);
var_dump($var->Image->attributes()->primary);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i don't want image's attribute. I want image url.

Comment: @pheaselegen Sorry. Apparently I did not understood your question.